# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, symfony, puppeteer

I'm trying to use Puppeteer v5.0.0 to generate PDFs of my application's page. To run the command to start the process I'm using Symfony's Process class. The command works normally when I type it manually in the command line but doesn't work when using Symfony.

I've tried

- Updating node version to v12.18.3 which some posts have recommended for me to do
- Using a generic website like `https://google.com`
- Using php's `exec`, but I'd like to use Symfony because of the input sanitation
- Changing the output file path to `public/file.pdf` (maybe the `/tmp` permissions weren't right?)
- Downgrading puppeteer to v4.0.0

Here's the code for running the command:

```
 $path = base_path();
        $filePath = '/tmp/pagePdf-'.time().'.pdf';
        $url = route('render.page', $request->all());

        $process = new Process(["node", "$path/resources/assets/js/takePdf.js", $url, $filePath]);
        $process->setTimeout(60);

        try{
            $process->mustRun();
            $process->wait();

            if(file_exists($filePath)){
                return response()->download($filePath)->deleteFileAfterSend();
            }else{
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }catch(ProcessFailedException $e){
            Log::info($e->getMessage());
            report($e);

            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

This is `takePdf.js`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        ],
    });

    // Parse arguments
    var args = process.argv;
    var indexes = [2,3];
    var arg_index = {};

    arg_index[2] = 'URL';
    arg_index[3] = 'File Path';

    indexes.forEach(function(index){
        if(typeof args[index] == 'undefined'){
            var parameter = arg_index[index];
            console.log('Missing Parameter: ' + parameter);
            browser.close();
            process.exit(1);
        }
    });

    var url = args[2] + '&token=' + process.env.RENDER_TOKEN;
    var filePath = args[3];

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    });
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}).catch(e => void 0);
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    await page.pdf({
        path: filePath,
        format: 'A4',
        printBackground: true,
        width: '1920px',
        height: '1080px'
    });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

When hitting the endpoint this is the exception I am getting back from the Process. Again, running on the command line works normally.

```
internal/util.js:209
        throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
        ^
    
    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
        at promisify (internal/util.js:209:11)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/forge/default/releases/20200709194844/node_modules/extract-zip/index.js:11:18)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/forge/default/releases/20200709194844/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/node/BrowserFetcher.js:48:39)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the process it was trying to use a different node version, the command line returned a higher version of node compared to the command. To fix this I had to pass the right path of the node to the process.

```
$process = new Process(["/path/to/node", "$path/resources/assets/js/takePdf.js", $url, $filePath]);
```